# Does psexec support input redirection?

Tags: psexec

I am trying to control a remote Python script via psexec, which reads commands from stdin, but I need to redirect psexec's input since psexec itself will be launched from another program. However, I have no luck making psexec accept redirected input. Is it supposed to work at all?

An example of what I'm trying to do, where *input* is a file containing input to the remote script:

```
psexec \\mymachine python c:\script.py < input
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way I was able to kinda accomplish what you're after:

`PsExec.exe -d \\\\192.168.1.1 cmd /k "echo list volume | diskpart"`

This would pass the commands "list volume" to the diskpart command. Additionally you can also try using cmd like this for you example:

`PsExec.exe -d \\\\192.168.1.1 cmd /k "python c:\script.py < input"`

Comment: I have taken to doing the latter, after copying the response file to the remote machine.  I set the command line up like this:

`copy input.txt \\machine\X$\WorkingDir && PsExec.exe \\machine -w X:\WorkingDir cmd /k "executable.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 < input.txt & del input.txt"`

This copies the file and then cleans it up afterwards.